# Enable pondering with Leela chess zero

Tags: engines, leela

I just got Leela Chess Zero up and running inside docker using [this](https://github.com/LeelaChessZero/lc0/wiki/Leela-Self-play-in-Docker) guide. Added a couple of weights from [here](https://github.com/dkappe/leela-chess-weights)

Now, when I run leela

```
$> lczero -w path/to/weight/file
go
info depth 16 nodes 435 nps 48 tbhits 0 score cp -437 time 9085 pv b5c4 d3c4 d5b4 ...
bestmove b5c4
```

I've used stockfish before, which also returns a ponder move

```
bestmove b5c4 ponder d3c4
```

[Here](http://blog.lczero.org/2018/09/guide-setting-up-leela-on-chess-gui.html) is described that you can use `--ponder` to enable it, but that option is not recognized. Is something like this also possible with Leela?

Furthermore, I've seen different weight files, where can I find good weight files?

Comment: You'll probably get fastest and best help by asking directly in the leela discord.

Answer (score 2):

After asking on the Discord as @Oscar Smith suggested in a comment, I got some results.

The person I asked said that you could download good weight files for Leela from this webpage: http://lczero.org/networks/

This was also said: "nT40.T8.610 (used in TCEC Sufi): https://www.dropbox.com/s/rmcf0lf1hes10gi/256x20.T8-swa-610000?dl=0 and currently in use in TCEC Rapid is 42547.pb.gz from above page. LCZero won Season 15 TCEC Superfinal  with above net T40.T8.610, but might not any more be strongest one."

I'm assuming that it's relavant to what you need.

Here is the Leela Chess Zero Discord link so you can find out more: https://discordapp.com/invite/pKujYxD